# What are some examples of things designed/engineered to require no maintenance?

Tags: usability-engineering, reliability

I've read somewhere that most items that are built by professional engineers (think roads, cars, etc) are built with some kind of maintenance in mind. In other words, things that are built well are built knowing they will need some upkeep. Roads need repaving or widening, and cars need regular mechanical maintenance in my example.

Are there any objects/items that are built/designed *specifically* so they can be left alone with very little to no maintenance? Things that can be "set and forgotten" as it were?

Comment: This is an interesting question but I don't see how this applies to UX. Except perhaps that repairs are an inconvenience and less repair means a better experience.

Comment: @Mayo I thought this would be a good place for this question (it's about design I suppose) but moving it somewhere more appropriate if needed would be good too :)

Comment: I'm not sure what we can learn from such a list. Are these objects designed differently in ways that's meaningful to discuss?

Comment: -kitchen utensils i.e. fork, knife, spoon    -plastic chairs    -tupperware     -flask    -bullets    -regular pencil...

these are just some examples, but there are tons of them if you really think about it.

Comment: A lot of disposable things are never maintained: cheap pens and pencils, medical supplies (hypodermics), clothing, etc. Even electronic things like DVD players and microwaves. (I just threw away a broken TV last week.) You ask about things that "require no maintenance," so maybe this isn't quite the list you're looking for. These are things where it's worth buying new ones rather than maintaining them. So I guess they're probably not designed for maintenance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "example of" questions doesn't have one definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Satellites
2. Underwater drilling wells
3. Fire Hydrants

Comment: All of them require maintenance for sure, especially 1, even if remotely done. As for 2... there are companies specialized exactly in underwater drilling wells maintenance, and they charge A LOT!. 3 requires very little maintenance, granted, but nowhere close to 0

Comment: There is nearly zero physical maintenance on satellites. I was interpreting hands on as opposed to digital.  Also, those underwater drilling wells to not require maintenance, they require repair. That's a huge difference.  They are DESIGNED to not need regular maintenance. :)

Comment: Still not sure about the UX community application, but this is a great list that addresses complex products designed for longevity and limited access.

Comment: If someone wanted to design something that needed minimal maintenance, then having examples is exactly what is needed.  I approve. :)